# Stop ytdl from sending messages to console

Tags: python, ytdl

When I load a video from ytdl, it prints: `[youtube] videoLink: Downloading webpage` in the console. How can I make it so it stops printing these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I think I figured out how. I just needed to define my ydl_opts like this:

```
ydl_opts = {
    'quiet': True
}
```